# Execute recursive function and save the callback

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have the following code. It runs a simple function and the same function needs to run. (Recursive)

```
var Skit = function(callback) {
    validSkit(Math.random(),function(skit,data){
        // Ajax callback
        if (skit == true) callback(data); // Works if skit is found
        else if (skit == false) Skit(callback); // Call Skit again [not working]
    });
}(function(skit){
    console.log("Valid skit found!");
});
```

I'm getting `Skit is undefined!` I know I could do this true simple `function Skit()..` call. But this is not my requirements. Is this possible?

Comment: Try `var Skit = function Skit(callback)`.

Comment: or rather `(function Skit(callback){`... This would be a classical named function expression.

Comment: The function expression is immediately invoked, and the function has no return value, hence the value of 'Skit' is undefined. What is it that you want this code to do though?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use a **named function expression** here:

```
(function Skit(callback) {
    validSkit(Math.random(),function(skit,data){
        // Ajax callback
        if (skit == true) callback(data); // Works if skit is found
        else if (skit == false) Skit(callback); // Call Skit again [not working]
    });
})(function(skit){
    console.log("Valid skit found!");
});
```

Note that the `Skit` name won't leak in the outside scope and it will be available for debug in the stack traces.

Answer (score 0):

In this case var `Skit` variable is the returned value.

```
(function (callback) {
...
})(function () {console.log('I am argument function')});
```

If you returned smth from it (after validSkit execution, for exampe, or before, whatever) then the value of Skit would be return value. As far as return statement is absent, it returns undefined by default.

So you need firstly to initiate function without calling it and then call it by its name:

```
 var Skit = function(callback) {
    validSkit(Math.random(),function(skit,data){
        // Ajax callback
        if (skit == true) callback(data); // Works if skit is found
        else if (skit == false) Skit(callback); // Call Skit again [not working]
    });
};

Skit(function(skit){
    console.log("Valid skit found!");
});
```